# UICollectionViewTransitionLayout and contentOffset on finish

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When UICollectionView finished interactive transition it scrolls to unexpected offset. Setting contentOffset in completion block for transition helps, but I see same invalid contentOffset in split second. It's no matter use standard UICollectionViewFlowLayout or custom layout. Is there are way to stick to cell for next layout? My code example

```
let nextLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout === layout1 ? layout2 : layout1
        let transition = collectionView.startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout(nextLayout) { (par1: Bool, par2: Bool) in
            //There was contentOffset setting code, that leads to blink
        }

        let initializer:(POPMutableAnimatableProperty!)->Void = {property in
            property.readBlock = {obj, values in
                values[0] = transition.transitionProgress
            }
            property.writeBlock = {obj, values in
                transition.transitionProgress = values[0]
                if let attrs: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = transition.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                    collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(attrs.frame.origin.x, attrs.frame.origin.y)
                }
            }
            property.threshold = 0.01
        }

        let springAnimation = POPSpringAnimation()
        let property = POPAnimatableProperty.propertyWithName("com.pop.property", initializer: initializer) as! POPAnimatableProperty
        springAnimation.springBounciness = 8.0
        springAnimation.dynamicsMass = 8.0
        springAnimation.property = property
        springAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        springAnimation.toValue = 1.0

        springAnimation.completionBlock = {anim, finished in
            if finished {
                transition.transitionProgress = 1.0
                self.collectionView.finishInteractiveTransition()
            }
        }
        transition.pop_addAnimation(springAnimation, forKey: "transitionProgress")
```

UPDATE:
Adding this code at start helped me, but I need to perform transition without additional scrolling before transition

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredVertically, animated: false)
```

"animated" flag should be false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer! It needs to override targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) in destination layout!

Comment: Works perfectly! One question (sorry for very late reply)- when the `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` is called, is the new layout data already set?